# Configurable Self-Reg not working for communities

Tags: lightning-community, self-registration

We have set up a community and have enabled self registration for external users , for self registration we have enabled Configurable Self-Reg Page , but when users try to self register , self registration is not happening and it throws an error 'Hmm. Something isn't right. Please try again' , is there anything that i am missing?

Comment: Please edit your original post to include more details.  What fields are you including?  Have you modified the Apex class?  What user is executing the registration?  Have set a debug log on the site guest user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your admin who set up communities should receive an email with error description.
2. You should be able to view the debug logs for the user who is set in the "Execute Registration As" field in Login & Registration in your community workspace.

Once you inspect debug logs or receive an email, you will see what was wrong and be able to fix it.